# SQL - Best way to limit access to small number of tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a login I've created on SQL Server 2008, it's a SQL Server login not using AD. I want to give them access to every table in two databases except the tables that I store login information in for sites and such. This is one table in each database. Ideally, I'd like them to automatically get access to any new tables added to either database without breaking that restriction on those two login info tables.

Comment: Create a separate schema for the login tables like `login`, then deny the user(s)/groups(s) access to do anything on the login schema. This solution will scale, if you end up have to added more tables to the login schema.

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, no idea on the downvotes, I guess some people don't like people asking for help.

Comment: When you say "get access" are looking at allowing them CRUD access or full control of the table to modify the table schema?

Answer (score 1):

Just place a [DENY ALL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188338.aspx)  on the table for that user. DENYs are always evaluated first, and will override the GRANT off SELECT to the overall schema:

```
DENY ALL ON [schema].[object] TO {user_name}
```

There is no reason to move the login table into a separate schema.